# calling a public method of the same class twice in another public method

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, public-method

i have two methods in **same class** *method1()* and *method2()*. *method 1()* is to read a 'String' and extract integers from that string and *method2 ()* is to perform a click operation. This click operation changes the 'string' which is the input of *method1 ()* . Evreythign is working fine but my problem is 
**Case 1**
When i am calling these two methods from another class in following way -

```
method1();-------- 1
method2();-------- 2
method1();---------3
```

i get a clear result which shows the result of line 1 is different from line 3 becuase the string was changed by line 2  BUT

**Case 2**
when i am calling method1() inside method2 () in the same class in the following way -

```
method2();{
method1();---------1
click statement of method2;
method1();---------2
}
```

and calling this method2(); from another class it doesnt work 
line 1  and line 2 gives same result.

where i am wrong in case 2 or its not possible to call a public method of the same class twice in another public method ?? please guide.

if you need code details here it is :-

```
 public void clickOnFaces(int n) {
       ArrayList<Integer> ratingLikes = ratingLikes(n);
        int likes = ratingLikes.get(0);
        int total = ratingLikes.get(1); 

        seleniumclient.elements(Mappings.face).get(n).click();

       ArrayList<Integer> updatedRatingLikes = ratingLikes(n);

            int c = updatedRatingLikes.get(0);
        int d = updatedRatingLikes.get(1);
    }





    public ArrayList ratingLikes(int n) {
        seleniumactions.waitForElement(Mappings.ratingLikes);
        ArrayList<Integer> likes = new ArrayList<>();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(seleniumclient.elements(Mappings.ratingLikes).get(n).getText());
            while (m.find()) {
                likes.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group()));
                 }
            return likes;
```

Issue is the value of 'c' and 'd' is same as 'likes' and 'total'. how ever they change when i keep only the click statement in clickonfaces() and call these mthods from different class example :

```
object.ratingLikes(int 0);
object.clickOnFaces(int 0);
object.ratingLikes(int 0);
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: i have added the code details @ArvindKumarAvinash

Comment: I can't understand it. Where is method 1. And where is method 2. clickOnFace do almost nothing except seleniumclient.elements. So, c and d for what

Comment: @LêHoàngDững . method 1 is rating likes() this find out the integers from a string "seleniumclient.elements(Mappings.ratingLikes).get(n).getText()" and method two is clickonFace() this method click on a webelement "(Mappings.face).get(n)", when this click happens the input string of method 1 "seleniumclient.elements(Mappings.ratingLikes).get(n).getText()" changes . so basically i want to know the integers in the string before and after the click. am i making any sense :( @ Lê Hoàng Dững

Comment: Try to set ratingList to a class variable.  set ratingLikes  method to void.  It will save  changes of list to ratingList.  If not success, you can run the debug to see what is going on your code